# Rails saves a Time instance to the wrong hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

So I have the following Time as a strong:

0:00:00.000

and I use the following strptime:

Time.strptime(times[0], "%H:%M:%S.%L")

**Expected Result**
0:00:00.000

**Actual Result**
6:00:00.000

I am 6 hours behind UTC outside of daylight savings.  So that might explain why it
s saving six hours ahead.  I've tried to wrap it in a Time.use_zone and set the zone to UTC but that still doesn't do the trick.

For now I have it subtracting six hours before saving the record.  But I'd like to figure out how to force it to save the timing to the correct hour.

Comment: I wonder if the following question/answers are helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909128/strptime-with-timezone

Comment: my understanding to set to UTC is using this command Time.zone = 'UTC', have you tried with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `Time.zone`

```rb
t = "0:00:00.000"
Time.zone.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S.%L")

=> Thu, 23 Jun 2022 00:00:00.000000000 CDT -05:00
```

Comment: Without changing the Zone, doing this Time.zone.strptime("0:00:00.000", "%H:%M:%S.%L") saved it correctly as UTC at 0 hours.  Thank you